# How to remove invalid element from DOM?

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom, xpath

We have the following code that lists the xpaths where `$value` is found.

We have detected for a given URL (see on picture) a non standard tag `td1` which in addition doesn't have a closing tag. Probably the site developers have put that there intentionally, as you see in the screen shot below.

This element creates problems identifying the corect XPath for nodes.

A broken Xpath example :

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tr[2]/td[2]/table[3]/tr[2]/**td1**/td[2]/span/u[1]
```

(as you see td1 is identified and chained in the Xpath)

We think by removing this element it helps us to build the valid XPath we are after.

A valid example is

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tr[2]/td[2]/table[3]/tr[2]/td[2]/span/u[1]
```

**How can we remove prior loading in DOMXpath? Do you have some other approach?**

We would like to remove all the invalid tags which may be other than td1, as h8, diw, etc...

```
private function extract($url, $value) {

        $dom = new DOMDocument();

        $file = 'content.txt';
        //$current = file_get_contents($url);
        $current = CurlTool::downloadFile($url, $file);
        //file_put_contents($file, $current);

        @$dom->loadHTMLFile($current);

        //use DOMXpath to navigate the html with the DOM
        $dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

        $elements = $dom_xpath->query("//*[text()[contains(., '" . $value . "')]]");
        var_dump($elements);
        if (!is_null($elements)) {

            foreach ($elements as $element) {
                var_dump($element);
                echo "\n1.[" . $element->nodeName . "]\n";

                $nodes = $element->childNodes;
                foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                    if( ($node->nodeValue != null) && ($node->nodeValue === $value) ) {
                        echo '2.' . $node->nodeValue . "\n";
                        $xpath = preg_replace("/\/text\(\)/", "", $node->getNodePath());
                        echo '3.' . $xpath . "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Good luck creating your own parser of DOM nodes. Look at other questions on Stackoverflow and you will see it is basically impossible to write a regular expression to fix bad code.

Comment: For the XPath it doesn't matter that td1 is not a valid HTML element. See http://codepad.org/eMKjNyXL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XPath to find the offending nodes and remove them, while promoting its children into its place in the DOM. Then your paths will be correct.

```
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$results = $dom_xpath->query('//td1'); // (or any offending element)
foreach ($results as $invalidNode)
{
    $parentNode = $invalidNode->parentNode;
    while ($invalidNode->childNodes)
    {
        $firstChild = $invalidNode->firstChild;
        $parentNode->insertBefore($firstChild,$invalidNode);
    }
    $parentNode->removeChild($invalidNode);
}
```

**EDIT:**

You could also build a list of offending elements by using a list of valid elements and negating it.

```
// Build list manually from the HTML spec:
// See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/section-index.html#elements-1
$validTags = array();

// Convert list to XPath:
$validTagsStr = '';
foreach ($validTags as $tag)
{
    if ($validTagsStr)
    {   $validTagsStr .= ' or ';    }
    $validTagsStr .= 'self::'.$tag;
}
$results = $dom_xpath->query('//*[not('.$validTagsStr.')');
```

Comment: This would help, if only i knew the broken tags. But i dont know them.

Comment: But, if i have a list with valid tags, this could be usefull

Comment: Here is the list: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/section-index.html#elements-1 I am working up a XPath clause to match ones that aren't in the list.

Comment: replace $results = $xpath->query('//td1'); with $results = $dom_xpath->query('//td1');

Comment: just tryed this code and i get this error : DOMNode::insertBefore() [<a href='domnode.insertbefore'>domnode.insertbefore</a>]: Couldn't add newnode as the previous sibling of refnode. My prepared code http://ideone.com/hY5LE (you need to run this locally)

Comment: Oh. Probably because we are reducing the set of child nodes in the loop. I'll rewrite it. -- Okay. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Sooo... perhaps `str_replace($current, "<td1 va-laign=\"top\">", "")` could do the trick?

Comment: We want a general solution, next time the tag may be <h8>,<diw>